# Can someone help me figure out why this simple function isn´t working?

Tags: c, project

I´m trying to copy a string that is in the comand line in argv to "op"

This is the function in C that i have been trying to fix and just can´t. I know it´s something pretty basic but it´s going over my head:

```
  int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   char op[90];
   strcpy(op,*argv[1]);
   printf("\n %s",op);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It might help to explain specifically and exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Note that `*argv[1]`is the first character of `argv[1]`.I guess you need `strcpy(op, argv[1]);`

Comment: The compiler can help you. Enable warnings, read what they are saying, try to fix them.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify the pointer sign when using [`strcpy()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html). Change:

```
strcpy(op, *argv[1]);
```

into:

```
strcpy(op, argv[1]);
```

But still you get [segfault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-a-segmentation-fault) if no argument is passed. You should create a condition to check if `argc != 1`, if it's true then instantly stop the program before anything unusual happens.

Comment: And to be really safe, you be using strncpy() instead of strcpy().